# Update query Get Latest record SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a tableA in which there are two fields Telephone,CallTime
There is another TableB which have three fields Name,Telephone1 and LastCallTime
I want to update TableB LastCallTime Field from TableA CallTime field whenever the Telephone1 field of TableB matches the Telephone field of TableA.
But there is an issue.
In TableA there are multiple records of Calltime against the Same Telephone.
i.e

- 123-456-7891  |   2016-01-01 00:02
- 456-789-8651  |   2015-03-07 02:09
- 123-456-7891  |   2016-06-10 12:02

like this,
So whenever i run the update query,it update the record with the record that is not latest. Is there anyway i can update the table with the latest calltime.For example the last record from above example which is the latest one.

```
UPDATE TableA 
SET LastCallTime = TableB.CallTime 

FROM TableB 
WHERE 
    TableA.Telephone = TableB.Telephone1
```

Comment: Can you include your update query in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `join` and aggregation:

```
update b
     set lastCallTime = a.callTime
     from tableB b join
          (select telephone, max(callTime) as callTime
           from tablea a
           group by telephone
          ) a
          on b.telephone = a.telephone;
```

Comment: Thank u sooo much @Gordon Linoff.
Your query works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a subquery in your `UPDATE` statement and use `TOP` to get the latest `CallTime`:

```
UPDATE b
    SET b.LastCallTime = (
        SELECT TOP 1 CallTime 
        FROM TableA a 
        WHERE a.Telephone = b.Telephone 
        ORDER BY a.CallTime DESC
    )
FROM TableB b
```

Comment: Note that this will set unmatched records to `NULL` . . . which might be good or bad, depending.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Update TABLEB B
set B.lastcalltime= A.calltime
(
select 
    telephone,
    calltime,
     from ( select 
                telephone,
                calltime,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by calltime desc) rnum
                from
                TABLEA )
                where rnum=1
            ) A
where B.telephone1=A.telephone
```